# Dice Roller Values

Tags: java, instance, dice

I am creating a dice rolling application with java.  I have a "Die" class that rolls a single die, and a "Dice" class that uses multiple instance variable of "die".  However, it only returns 0 for my values.  The Die class on its own works and will roll a random number, but I can not figure out how to get multiple rolls in my "Dice" class.  Any help is appreciated.

Dice Class

```
public class Dice {
    Die die1=new Die();
    Die die2=new Die();
    private int die1Value;
    private int die2Value;
    private int sum;
    public Dice() {
        die1Value=0;
        die2Value=0;
    }
    public int getDie1Value() {
        return die1Value;
    }
    public int getDie2Value() {
        return die2Value;
    }
    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
    public void roll() {
        die1Value=die1.getValue();
        die2Value=die2.getValue();
        sum=die1Value+die2Value;
    }
    public void printRoll() {
        System.out.println("Die 1: "+die1Value);
        System.out.println("Die 2: "+die2Value);
        System.out.println("Total: "+sum);
        if (sum==7) {
            System.out.println("Craps!");
        } else if (die1Value==1 && die2Value==1) {
            System.out.println("Snake Eyes!");
        } else if (die1Value==6 && die2Value==6) {
            System.out.println("Box Cars!");
        } else {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Die Class

```
package a3.ben;

public class Die {
    private int value;
    public Die() {

    }
    public void roll() {
        value=(int) (Math.random()*6)+1;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `die.roll`. Try changing the `roll` method in `Dice` to include rolling both dice before getting their values.

```java
public void roll() {
    die1.roll(); // change the value of both dice
    die2.roll();
    die1Value = die1.getValue();
    die2Value = die2.getValue();
    sum = die1Value + die2Value;
}
```

Also added some spaces around operators like `=` and `+` for readability

Comment: By the way, to generate a random number in Java, Joshua Bloch (Who worked on the java.math package) in his book "Effective Java" suggests to use the static method `Random.nextInt(n)` . It's less predictable and more efficient.